# How to multiply a columns in a matrix by a different constant (per column) and then summing each row up in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

For a project, I have a set amount of orders coming in and I am trying to calculate the total for each total. After multiplying each column (number of each item) of the matrix by a set constant (each price pertains to a different column in the matrix), I would like to sum all the cells in each row so that I can find the total price per each order. This is the code I have so far:

```
%A is the matrix of item types and quantities of each item

%A = |OrderNumber  Kitkat   Hershey   Reese's .....  Rolo|
     |  1            3        4        2      .....   4  |
     |  2            4        10       9      .....   2  |
     |  3            7        8        0      .....   0  |
     |.....         ....     ...      ...     ..... .....|

candyPrice = [3 4 3 ........];
orderTotalPrice = {}; 
for i = 1:10
  for k = 2:10
    orderTotalPrice(i) = A(i,k).*candyPrice(k)+orderTotalPrice;        
end
end
```

I am getting error messages when I run this code, saying that "Undefined function 'plus' for input arguments of type 'cell'."

Comment: Try `A{i,k}` instead?

Comment: Is this not exactly what a matrix-vector product is? Or have I misunderstood the question? If A is a matrix and x a vector, then Ax is the sum of the columns of A weighted by x.

Answer (score 4):

### For the question title:

> "**multiply columns in a matrix by a different constant (per column) and then summing each row up in Matlab?**"

one symbol, `*` will do this, (as mentioned in comments as vector-matrix product)

What you are trying to calculate is equivalent to

```
orderTotalPrice = candyPrice*matA
```

where candyPrice is a 1xn vector and matA is nxm (n being the number of item types and m being the number of orders...)

### For OP's code

To use this method with the cell A we need to

- Remove the order numbers and titles
- Convert from cell to matrix
- Transpose (to be numitemtypes x numorders)

So the one-liner which performs all this is:

```
orderTotalPrice = candyPrice*cell2mat(A(2:end,2:end)).'
```

with the test data

```
A = 

    'orderNo'    'item1'    'item2'    'item3'
    [      1]    [    2]    [    1]    [    3]
    [      2]    [    3]    [    2]    [    3]
    [      3]    [    1]    [    3]    [    3]


candyPrice =

   100    10     1
```

we get

```
orderTotalPrice = candyPrice*cell2mat(A(2:end,2:end)).'

orderTotalPrice =

   213   323   133
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `p1 = bsxfun(@times,A(:,2:end),candyPrice)` to compute the prices of all products. The total order price for each candy is `p2 = sum(p1,2)` and the total price is `p = sum(p2)`.

---

Alternatively, you adjust your code like this:

```
candyPrice = [3 4 3 ........];
orderTotalPrice = zeros(1,10);
for i = 1:10
    for k = 2:10
        orderTotalPrice(i) = A(i,k).*candyPrice(k)+orderTotalPrice(i);
    end
end
total = sum(orderTotalPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the orderNumber should not be multiplied with anything, otherwise it won't make any sense.

Therefore, I assume that `size(candyPrice,2)` equals `size(A,2)-1`

Then the vectorized code would be as follows:

```
orderTotalPrice = sum(repmat(candyPrice,[size(A,1) 1]).*A(:,2:end),2);
```